# iterate two list with different size

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, proxy

```
import itertools
Value = ['178.217.107.8:53281', '91.90.191.238:8080', '27.116.51.114:8080']
content = ['link1','link2','link3']

for a,b in zip(Value , itertools.cycle(content)):
   print(a,b)
```

what I am Looking for is if in the first list(LIST OF PROXIES) suppose any of the proxy is not working then pass and move to a next one in the list, parallely the element in the content list that is in the current stage should remain same.

for eg:
for first element the output is :
178.217.107.8:53281 Link1

but if 178.217.107.8:53281 throws error then take value of 'a' in the loop as 
and give output as 91.90.191.238:8080 Link1

Comment: @blhsing If you could help

Comment: @blhsing can you help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code below:

```
list_of_proxies = ['178.217.107.8:53281', '91.90.191.238:8080', '27.116.51.114:8080']
list_of_links = ['link1','link2','link3']
for proxy in list_of_proxies:
    for link in list_of_links:
        # call some method to check if the proxy worked and store in a variable
        success = method_call(proxy, link) # assuming return type as boolean
        if !success:
            break
        else:
            # remove the successful link from the list, depending on your exact requirement
            list_of_links.remove(link)
```

Comment: i do not want to use the nesed for loop rather i want to iterate the two list simultaneously which is accomplished using the zip method but the only problem is that if one the element in one list throws error it moves to the next index of the element in both the list rather i want to move to next index of the list element that throws error

Comment: because for each proxy in list of proxies it will iterate all the elements in list of links but i want to iterate one proxy and one link at the same time

Answer (score 0):

What you need in this case is to iterate through your links, and for every link, cycle through the proxy list with `itertools.cycle` until you succeed in getting the link.

Pseudo-code:

```
from itertools import cycle
Value = ['178.217.107.8:53281', '91.90.191.238:8080', '27.116.51.114:8080']
content = ['link1','link2','link3']
proxies = cycle(Value)

for link in content:
    while True:
        response = get_link_via_proxy(link, next(proxies))
        if response.is_success:
           break
    do_something_with(response)
```

Comment: i want to iterate one proxy and one link at the same time basically i want to open every next link using a different proxy IP

Comment: I see. You need to use `itertools.cycle` and then use `next` to obtain the next proxy in the list. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: appreciate your help in the pseudo code above but could not implement it efficiently hence i have pasted the entire code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397614/iterate-the-for-loop-in-selenium-for-list-with-different-size if you could have a look at it and edit it accordingly and help me